# Serializing models polymorphically in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-serializer

I've a inheritance model like this,

Base class,

```
class PrivateMessage(Base):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='privatemessage_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(PrivateRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='message_set', null=True)
    message_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

Children.

```
class PrivateTextMessage(PrivateMessage):
        body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class PrivateImageMessage(PrivateMessage):
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=attachment_images_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

I'm serializing them polymorphically,

```
class PublicMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PublicMessage
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, PublicTextMessage):
            return PublicTextMessageSerializer(obj, context=self.context).to_representation(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, PublicImageMessage):
            return PublicImageMessageSerializer(obj, 
        return super(PublicMessageSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)


class PublicTextMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    receiver = RoomSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PublicTextMessage
        fields = ('id', 'sender', 'receiver', 'body', 'message_type', 'created', 'modified',)


class PublicImageMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    receiver = RoomSerializer(read_only=True)
    image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PublicImageMessage
        fields = ('id', 'sender', 'receiver', 'image', 'message_type', 'created', 'modified',)
```

The problem is that only the fields that are there in the base class are rendered by the serializer. For example the image field in the PublicImageMessage never gets rendered.

Can someone help me with the conditional rendering where all fields of the class are rendered.

> PS: The classes have a PublicMessageType object. I've tried using that
>   and serializing, but outside of that being clunky, in that case the
>   fields are rendered with null value.

Comment: Have you considered doing [nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)? Your data serialization would have one more layer (you wouldn't get a list of objects but a dict containing that list).

Comment: @AuroraWang I don't think this is the perfect use case for nested serilaizers, I think issue needs a way to make polymorphism work correctly in django.

Comment: Change `get_serializer_class` on the viewset instead. Also if `PrivateMessage` is not abstract then all of your `obj`s are probably of this type (not descendants) so `if`s are never fired.